# Display Form in Admin Panel and Save data to Database

Tags: wp-admin, wpdb, wp-list-table

I have a `Add New` Button in Admin Panel like below image.

[image]

I would like to display a Form like below image and save data to a Database after clicking the `Add New` Button.

[image]

How can I do that ?

I am displaying data using wp_list_table from Database.

Comment: It sounds like you should just be using a [custom post type](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/#custom-post-types).

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. I am new WordPress. Could you please help me with some easy tutorials ? Thanks.

Comment: Just Google search for “custom post type”. There’s no shortage of resources on the subject.